# Optimizing PHP code with two foreach loops

Tags: php

I have an array that consists of the keys:

```
$countries = ['EU', 'UK', 'Asia'];
```

Another array that consists of further elements based on those keys:

```
$countries_array=['UK'=>['London', 'Birmingham', 'Manchester'], 'EU'=> ['Germany','Netherlands'] , 'Asia'=> ['Pakistan','Bangladesh','China']];

$mid_countries[];
```

I want to pass through all the elements, check if they are empty or not and then further create another array. I have written a code and it works fine. But it has foreach loops. Is there any way that I could optimize this code?

```
foreach ($countries as $each_country) {
    if (!empty($countries_array["$each_country"][0])) {
        foreach ($countries_array["$each_country"] as $value) {
            $mid_countries[] = array("wildcard" => array("$each_country" => $value. "*"));
        }
    }
}
```

Expected result:

```
    array(8) { 
[0]=> array(1) { ["wildcard"]=> array(1) { ["EU"]=> string(8) "Germany*" } } [1]=> array(1) { ["wildcard"]=> array(1) { ["EU"]=> string(12) "Netherlands*"}} 
[2]=> array(1) { ["wildcard"]=> array(1) { ["UK"]=> string(7) "London*" } } [3]=> array(1) { ["wildcard"]=> array(1) { ["UK"]=> string(11) "Birmingham*" } } [4]=> array(1) { ["wildcard"]=> array(1) { ["UK"]=> string(11) "Manchester*" } } [5]=> array(1) { ["wildcard"]=> array(1) { ["Asia"]=> string(9) "Pakistan*" } } [6]=> array(1) { ["wildcard"]=> array(1) { ["Asia"]=> string(11) "Bangladesh*"}} 
[7]=> array(1) { ["wildcard"]=> array(1) { ["Asia"]=> string(6) "China*" } } }
```

Comment: Your `$countries_array` contains syntax errors.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Your code shouldn't work.

Comment: You probably won't need the second foreach loop at all if you can tell us how would you further use `$mid_countries` . Now I am seeing not even the first one.

Comment: @vivek_23 It's a new array, that I need to use further in another PHP function.

Comment: @MariumMalik Ok, but how would you use it further? Is that a lookup to retrieve a wildcard format?

Comment: @vivek_23 It's for my elastic search query.

Comment: What you have shown makes little sense. Apart from the syntax errors, using stuff like `['UK']` as key (which is itself an _array_ containing one string element) should get you _Warning:  Illegal offset type_ …

Comment: @MariumMalik Like if someone searches for `London`, then what would you show them?

Comment: @misorude I have just given you people an example. It's not my actual data.

Comment: It is not about the _data_ (content), but about the _structure_. This doesn’t even make sense as an example. If you give examples, then at least get them structurally right, please.

Comment: @misorude About your first comment, my data is actually similar and it's working. PHP is not throwing any illegal offset type error.

Comment: @Raptor I fixed that, it was missing closing bracket.

Comment: To be honest - I think the way you have it now is the easiest (and probably fastest) way of doing it.  You can use some `array_` functions, but it's quite a straight forward process as it is.

Comment: @NigelRen Okay! Thanks! That's what I actually wanted to know. I was wondering if I could avoid first foreach.

Comment: _“my data is actually similar and it's working. PHP is not throwing any illegal offset type error”_ - then your data is _not_ actually of that structure, or you have PHP configured not to show such errors. And it can not really be working either, if you really use `['UK']` as a _key_. `$foo = [['bar'] => 'baz']; var_dump($foo);` would give you said warning, and a completely empty array as result (_because_ such a key is not valid.)

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @Andreas Expected result is $mid_countries array with wild card as they key and each country as it's value along with '*'

Comment: @misorude I put extra square brackets. That was a mistake from my end.

Comment: @NigelRen Added the output

Answer (score -1):

I think you expected this (Code updated use its working in single loop)

```
foreach ($countries_array as $key=>$value) {         
   $tmp=implode('*#'.$key.'#',$value);
   $tmp='#'.$key.'#'.$tmp."*";
   $tmp=str_replace('#'.$key.'#',"\"}},{\"wildcard\":{\"".$key."\":\"",$tmp);
   $result=$result.substr($tmp,3)."\"}}"; 
}
$result="[".ltrim($result,"\"}},")."]";
$result=json_decode($result,true);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I get array to string conversion notice, for the first line.

Comment: expected output?

Comment: give me examples ?

Comment: Added it in the question